# CUDA graph does not run as expected

Tags: cuda, cuda-graphs

I'm using the following the code to learn about how to use "CUDA graphs". The parameter `NSTEP` is set as 1000, and the parameter `NKERNEL` is set as 20. The kernel function `shortKernel` has three parameters, it will perform a simple calculation.

```cpp
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>

#define N 131072 // tuned such that kernel takes a few microseconds
#define NSTEP 1000
#define NKERNEL 20
#define BLOCKS 256
#define THREADS 512

#define CHECK(call)                                                         \
    do {                                                                    \
        const cudaError_t error_code = call;                                \
        if (error_code != cudaSuccess) {                                    \
            printf("CUDA Error\n");                                         \
            printf("    File:   %s\n", __FILE__);                           \
            printf("    Line:   %d\n", __LINE__);                           \
            printf("    Error code: %d\n", error_code);                     \
            printf("    Error text: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error_code)); \
            exit(1);                                                        \
        }                                                                   \
    } while (0)

__global__ void shortKernel(float * out_d, float * in_d, int i){
      int idx=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
        if(idx<N) out_d[idx]=1.23*in_d[idx] + i;
        
}

void test2() {
  cudaStream_t stream;
  cudaStreamCreate(&stream);
  cudaSetDevice(0);

  float x_host[N], y_host[N];
  // initialize x and y arrays on the host
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x_host[i] = 2.0f;
    y_host[i] = 2.0f;
  }
  float *x, *y, *z;
  CHECK(cudaMalloc((void**)&x, N*sizeof(float)));
  CHECK(cudaMalloc((void**)&y, N*sizeof(float)));
  CHECK(cudaMalloc((void**)&z, N*sizeof(float)));
  cudaMemcpy(x, x_host, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  cudaEvent_t begin, end;
  CHECK(cudaEventCreate(&begin));
  CHECK(cudaEventCreate(&end));
  // start recording
  cudaEventRecord(begin, stream);
  bool graphCreated=false;
  cudaGraph_t graph;
  cudaGraphExec_t instance;
  // Run graphs
  for(int istep=0; istep<NSTEP; istep++){
    if(!graphCreated){
      cudaStreamBeginCapture(stream, cudaStreamCaptureModeGlobal);
      for(int ikrnl=0; ikrnl<NKERNEL; ikrnl++){
        shortKernel<<<BLOCKS, THREADS, 0, stream>>>(y, x, ikrnl);
      }
      cudaStreamEndCapture(stream, &graph);
      cudaGraphNode_t* nodes = NULL;
      size_t num_nodes = 0;
      CHECK(cudaGraphGetNodes(graph, nodes, &num_nodes));
      std::cout << "Num of nodes in the graph: " << num_nodes
                << std::endl;
      CHECK(cudaGraphInstantiate(&instance, graph, NULL, NULL, 0));
      graphCreated=true;
    }
    CHECK(cudaGraphLaunch(instance, stream));
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);
  }  // End run graphs
  cudaEventRecord(end, stream);
  cudaEventSynchronize(end);
  float time_ms = 0;
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&time_ms, begin, end);
  std::cout << "CUDA Graph - CUDA Kernel overall time: " << time_ms << " ms" << std::endl;

  cudaMemcpy(y_host, y, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    std::cout << "res " << y_host[i] << std::endl;
  }
  // Free memory
  cudaFree(x);
  cudaFree(y);

}

int main() {
    test2();
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My expected results are shown as the following:

```bash
res 2.46
res 3.46
res 4.46
res 5.46
res 6.46
...
```

However, the actual results are shown like this:

```bash
res 21.46
res 21.46
res 21.46
res 21.46
res 21.46
res 21.46
...
```

It seems that the all kernels' parameter `i` is set as `NKERNEL-1`. I am very confused about it, could someone give any explanations? Thanks!

I had changed the `for loop` as follows:

```cpp
  // Run graphs
  for(int istep=0; istep<NSTEP; istep++){
    if(!graphCreated){
      cudaStreamBeginCapture(stream, cudaStreamCaptureModeGlobal);
      for(int ikrnl=0; ikrnl<NKERNEL; ikrnl++){
        if(ikrnl == 0)
          shortKernel<<<BLOCKS, THREADS, 0, stream>>>(y, x, 0);
        else if(ikrnl == 1)
          shortKernel<<<BLOCKS, THREADS, 0, stream>>>(y, x, 1);
        else if(ikrnl == 2)
          shortKernel<<<BLOCKS, THREADS, 0, stream>>>(y, x, 2);
        else
          shortKernel<<<BLOCKS, THREADS, 0, stream>>>(y, x, ikrnl);
      }
      cudaStreamEndCapture(stream, &graph);
      cudaGraphNode_t* nodes = NULL;
      size_t num_nodes = 0;
      CHECK(cudaGraphGetNodes(graph, nodes, &num_nodes));
      std::cout << "Num of nodes in the graph: " << num_nodes
                << std::endl;
      CHECK(cudaGraphInstantiate(&instance, graph, NULL, NULL, 0));
      graphCreated=true;
    }
    CHECK(cudaGraphLaunch(instance, stream));
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);
  }  // End run graphs
```

However, the results are still the same:

```bash
res 21.46
res 21.46
res 21.46
res 21.46
res 21.46
res 21.46
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results are expected and correct.

Every time you run the graph, this entire for-loop gets executed:

```
  for(int ikrnl=0; ikrnl<NKERNEL; ikrnl++){
    shortKernel<<<BLOCKS, THREADS, 0, stream>>>(y, x, ikrnl);
  }
```

After the first iteration of that for-loop, the results will all be 2.46, after the second iteration the results will all be 3.46, and after the 20th iteration (`ikrnl = 19`) the results will all be 21.46.

Every time you run the graph, you will get that same result.

Expecting any kind of variation in the result such as this:

```
res 2.46
res 3.46
res 4.46
res 5.46
res 6.46
```

Is completely illogical, because *every thread is doing precisely the same thing*.  Every thread starts with the same value in `x`, and does the same calculation on it.  There is no reason to expect any difference between `y[0]` and `y[1]`, for example.

Rather than trying to wade through CUDA graphs, its clear you don't have a good grasp of what the kernel is doing.  My suggestion would be that you write an ordinary CUDA code that calls that kernel just once, without any CUDA graph usage, and study the output.  After that, you can put a for-loop around the kernel, and watch the result behavior after every iteration of the for-loop.  You don't need CUDA graphs to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I understand what is going on with my codes. I am a new hand in `cuda`, and thanks for the suggestions!